# OpenCV cannot open video Windows 8.1

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv, video-capture

I am using OpenCV with Java.
I intend to open a video capture object and read frames from a video.

However, the code

```
VideoCapture camera = new VideoCapture("C:\\myvideo.mp4");

        if (!camera.isOpened())
            System.out.println("Cannot open file");
```

Constantly fails.
The exact same code works perfectly fine on my old Windows 7 system.

I assure you OpenCV and Eclipse are configured correctly and exactly same as the other Windows7 system. Media player plays the video correctly.

What may cause the VideoCapture to never open ?

Comment: Interesting, possible bug here. Try creating an issue on opencv dev zone if you don'n get any resposnse that will fix your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a windows path problem.
The PATH environment variable must be set to , for example "C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin".
The bin folder contains some files that are responsible for decoding videos.
Apparently this is the only solution, playing around with eclipse build paths has no effect.